# Django profiling

Tags: python, django, profiling, django-debug-toolbar

I want to profile my Django App. My requirements are

1.inspection of sql queries

2.list of modules called for each request and their run time

3.Support for Ajax request

4.Web Page performance results like Yslow

5.Tracking vulnerabilities in the page

What is your Reccomendation?

**UPDATE:**

I Came across the following two snippets for django profiling

[Interactive Profiling middleware](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2126/)

[Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Do anybody tell which one will be better suited for my needs?

Comment: Why not use firebug for 3 and 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 . [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Or in Django >= 1.3

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

2 . [django-timelog](https://github.com/garethr/django-timelog) or [django-dowser](https://github.com/munhitsu/django-dowser)

3 . [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome dev tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html)

4 . [Page speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) provides number of tools

5 . [nmap](http://nmap.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Savanovich. I m using python 2.4.3 and django 1.3.I want to kmow Django-timelog supports python 2.4?

Comment: I also want to know any tutorials on how to use nmap on django site.